# confused between choosing MVP or MVC for creating forums

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns

i'm having a trouble with the following:

i've been implemented the forum system of a website in MVP pattern and it works great. so why most of the web developers including the big ones choose NOT to use this pattern for creating forum systems?? as far as i know they go for MVC pattern while the MVP provides us a better seperation.

Comment: +1 for my new knowledge, This website has pros and cons, It might answer your question :) http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/kim/archive/2007/11/10/end-of-confusion-mvp-vs-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In MVP the presenter refers back to the view, but in MVC the controller doesn't refer back to the view. View and Model are synchronised with data.

Answer (score 0):

Who are you referring to by big web developers?
Here is Ray Ryan from Google advocating MVP over MVC: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDuhR18-EdM#t=21m26s

Comment: scott hanselman and rick strahl for example! so what is their technical reason(s)? i wish i could have ask them!